# django: How to pass variable to class?

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-2.x, django-generic-views, django-1.4

urls.py

```
url(r'^customer/(?P<name>[^\s]+)/$', customerDetailView.as_view(), name="customerDetailView"), #pass 'name' variable
```

and

views.py

```
class customerDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'customerDetail'
    template_name = "customer.html"
    allow_empty = True

    def __init__(self, name=None, *args):
        self.name = name # name is 'None'... Why...?

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Customer.objects.get(name=self.name)
```

I just request '192.168.1.5/customer/abc/', but 'name' is none...

How to receive 'name'?
What should I do?

edit-----

views.py

```
class customerDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'customerDetail'
    template_name = "customer.html"
    allow_empty = True
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        self.name = kwargs['name']
    """
    def get_queryset(self):
        # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        self.name = self.kwargs['name'] # Thanks  Kay Zhu!!
        return Customer.objects.get(name=self.name)
```

I apply code you answered.

Then, I get a error

```
Generic detail view customerDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

So I need 'pk'...

What should I do?

Comment: I've updated the answer to address the second problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the parameter with `self.kwargs['name']`. Further, `get_queryset` should return a queryset instead.

You also need to use `pk` instead of `name` in your URL if you want to use `DetailView` generic view. After that you only need to define `model = Customer` and `slug_field = 'name'` in your `customerDetailView` class and it should work. You do not need to access `self.kwargs['name']` at all. [[source]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py)

If you *really* want to use `<name>` in your URL, you also need to change `slug_url_kwarg` to `name` (in addition to `slug_field = 'name'`:

```
class customerDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'customerDetail'
    template_name = "customer.html"
    allow_empty = True
    model = Customer
    slug_field = 'name'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'name'
    # no need to override any methods here
```

or override `get_object` by:

```
def get_object(self):
    return get_object_or_404(Customer, name=self.kwargs['name'])
```

without modifying `slug_field` and `slug_url_kwarg` in your class.

Comment: I want to get 'pk'. so 'self.pk = Customer.objects.get(name=self.name).pk'<- This code put __init__. but still break...

Comment: @chobo Ah I see, iirc, you will need to change `<name>` to `<pk>` and all these `name` to `pk` as well. I will let you know if I recall something else..

Comment: @chobo Ok, found the reference: `The DetailView generic view expects the primary key value captured from the URL to be called "pk", so we've changed poll_id to pk for the generic views.`
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial04/#use-generic-views-less-code-is-better

Comment: Yeah, So I need 'pk', and I will get 'pk' by 'Customer.objects.get(name=self.name).pk'. But I don't know how...